# What's the error of numpy.polyfit?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I want to use `numpy.polyfit` for physical calculations, therefore I need the magnitude of the error.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you specify `full=True` in your call to [`polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html), it will include extra information:

```
>>> x = np.arange(100)
>>> y = x**2 + 3*x + 5 + np.random.rand(100)
>>> np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
array([ 0.99995888,  3.00221219,  5.56776641])
>>> np.polyfit(x, y, 2, full=True)
(array([ 0.99995888,  3.00221219,  5.56776641]), # coefficients
 array([ 7.19260721]), # residuals
 3, # rank
 array([ 11.87708199,   3.5299267 ,   0.52876389]), # singular values
 2.2204460492503131e-14) # conditioning threshold
```

The residual value returned is the sum of the squares of the fit errors, not sure if this is what you are after:

```
>>> np.sum((np.polyval(np.polyfit(x, y, 2), x) - y)**2)
7.1926072073491056
```

In version 1.7 there is also a `cov` keyword that will return the covariance matrix for your coefficients, which you could use to calculate the uncertainty of the fit coefficients themselves.

Comment: do you know if np.polyfit uses TLS (Total Least Squares also known as Orthogonal Least Squares), or OLS (Ordinary Least Squares) to find the best fit?

Comment: `np.polyfit` uses the Ordinary least Squares algorithm using `np.linalg.lstsq` similar to `scipy.linalg.lstsq`. `scipy.odr` implements the Orthogonal Least Squares algorithm, or more precisely the Orthogonal Distance Regression.

Answer (score 26):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

```
Returns
-------
p : ndarray, shape (M,) or (M, K)
    Polynomial coefficients, highest power first.
    If `y` was 2-D, the coefficients for `k`-th data set are in ``p[:,k]``.

residuals, rank, singular_values, rcond : present only if `full` = True
    Residuals of the least-squares fit, the effective rank of the scaled
    Vandermonde coefficient matrix, its singular values, and the specified
    value of `rcond`. For more details, see `linalg.lstsq`.
```

Which means that if you can do a fit and get the residuals as:

```
 import numpy as np
 x = np.arange(10)
 y = x**2 -3*x + np.random.random(10)

 p, res, _, _, _ = numpy.polyfit(x, y, deg, full=True)
```

Then, the `p` are your fit parameters, and the `res` will be the residuals, as described above.  The `_`'s are because you don't need to save the last three parameters, so you can just save them in the variable `_` which you won't use.  This is a convention and is not required.

---

@Jaime's answer explains what the residual means.  Another thing you can do is look at those squared deviations as a function (the sum of which is `res`).  This is particularly helpful to see a trend that didn't fit sufficiently.  `res` can be large because of statistical noise, or possibly systematic poor fitting, for example:

```
x = np.arange(100)
y = 1000*np.sqrt(x) + x**2 - 10*x + 500*np.random.random(100) - 250

p = np.polyfit(x,y,2) # insufficient degree to include sqrt

yfit = np.polyval(p,x)

figure()
plot(x,y, label='data')
plot(x,yfit, label='fit')
plot(x,yfit-y, label='var')
```

So in the figure, note the bad fit near `x = 0`:
[image: polyfit]