# How to measure the quality of a best fit line in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, best-fit-curve

I have some data points to plot, and would like to add a best fit line to the graph, and then output the relevant metrics to indicate the quality of the best fit line.

I could plot the data, and `polyfit`is a function I used to add the best fit line. However, I am just wondering how could I get the metrics that indicates the quality of the best fit line?

I don't see `polyfit` returns any metrics (i.e. min square error value).

Data:

```
0,1717
1,1761
2,1961
3,1711
4,1285
5,976
6,721
7,428
8,313
9,297
10,375
11,521
12,678
13,752
14,728
15,758
16,741
17,812
18,845
19,863
20,933
21,1169
22,1523
23,1779
```

Comment: You could take a look at [What's the error of numpy.polyfit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15721053/1730674)

Comment: @Kevin also [**t-test**](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) is one way to go and test the goodness of fit.

Comment: perhaps this would be helpful? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: @askewchan & @corvid, you mean... instead of using the polyfit, I should compose my own polynomial function then use the `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`?

Comment: @Dalek, but how can I get the error from the best fit line by using the `polyfit` function?

Comment: @Kevin, no need to use `curve_fit`, you can get the residuals directly from `polyfit` as mentioned by both answers at the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

mean squared error is one measure.

if you have numpy arrays of each point on your line and data:

```
numpy.mean((data - line_vals) ** 2)
```

edit:
to get line_vals, if you have an equation y=mx+b for a line:

```
line_vals = b + m * numpy.linspace(0, 23, 24)
```

Comment: I used the `polyfit` function without having composed my own polynomial function... do you happen to know how can I get the `line_vals` from there?

Comment: @Kevin, you could use `np.polyval` on the results from `np.polyfit`.  Beware of the mismatch described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18767992/1730674)