# Polynomial Regression values generated too far from the coordinates

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, regression, data-science

As per the  the below code for Polynomial Regression coefficients value, when I calculate the regression value at any x point. Value obtained is way more away from the equivalent y coordinate (specially for the below coordinates). Can anyone explain why the difference is so high, can this be minimized or any flaw in understanding. The current requirement is not a difference of more 150 at every point.

```
import  numpy as np
x=[0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]
y=[0,885,3517,5935,8137,11897,10125,13455,14797,15925,16837,17535,18017,18285,18328,18914,19432,19879,20249,20539,20746]                                                                                                     
z=np.polyfit(x,y,3)
print(z)
```

I have also tried various various codes available in java, but the coefficient values are same every where for this data. Please help with the understanding.
For example

```
0.019168 * N^3 + -5.540901 * N^2 + 579.846493 * N + -1119.339450
```

N equals 5 Value equals 1643.76649
Y value 885
N equals 10 Value equals 4144.20338
Y value 3517
N equals 100; Value=20624.29985 
 Y value 20746

Comment: Hi neer, welcome on StackOverflow! Would be nice if you shared what else have you tried (if anything) or what are your hyphoteses on the problem. It indeed seems that with a polynomial regression of degree 100 you match your residual target. With an higher degree you probably would match the target for all x and y. Additionally, since the minimization problem involves no stochastic computations, results will be the same whatever software you use.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial fit performs as expected. There is no error here, just a great deviation in your data. You might want to rescale your data though. If you add the parameter `full=True` to `np.polyfit`, you will receive additional information, including the residuals which essentially is the sum of the square fit errors. See this other [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721053/) for more details.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import  numpy as np

x = [0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100]
y = [0,885,3517,5935,8137,11897,10125,13455,14797,15925,16837,17535,18017,18285,18328,18914,19432,19879,20249,20539,20746]

m = max(y)
y = [p/m for p in y] # rescaled y such that max(y)=1, and dimensionless

z, residuals, rank, sing_vals, cond_thres = np.polyfit(x,y,3,full=True)

print("Z: ",z) # [ 9.23914285e-07 -2.67082878e-04  2.79497972e-02 -5.39544708e-02]

print("resi:", residuals) # 0.02188 : quite decent, depending on WHAT you're measuring ..

Z = [z[3] + q*z[2] +  q*q*z[1] + q*q*q*z[0] for q in x]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.plot(x,Z,'r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you run the below code,  it gives the following values which are way away from the coordinates. My question is whether we can fix this difference if not why:  for i in x:
    print(p(i))

Comment: It print the values :-1119.339450404673
1643.766421983809
4144.202868832156
6396.345534455371
8414.57006316846
10213.252099286421
11806.767287124265
13209.49127099699
14435.799695219604
15500.068204107105
16416.672441974504
17199.988053136796
17864.390681908993
18424.25597260609
18893.9595695431
19287.87711703502
19620.384259396855
19905.856640943606
20158.66990599029
20393.19969885189
20623.821663843428
20158.66990599029

Comment: @neer Yes, of course they are far away! Your data points have values values higher 15000. Difference requirements of 150 (as you write) is less than 1% deviation!! That is harsh, and is probably way to strict... obviously heavily dependent on what you are actually measuring?

Comment: I would suggest having some sort of relative difference requirement, and not an absolute one. I've rescaled the data in the plot to get a relative view. This is cleaner, and dimensionless.

Comment: @neer I've updated the answer to include the fitting error/residual. I suggest taking a look into its (uncommonly good) [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals). If my answer helped you solve your issue, I'd appreciate if you *accepted* it, and if not, I might suggest that you rephrase your question, maybe on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Upvoted for high quality answer. @magnus please see my answer which, though analytically  different, agrees with your answer here.

Comment: @neer It is impossible to comment on the differences on your two data sets without actually having detailed insight on how the data i produced. In terms of scientific polynomial fitting, nothing here is wrong. The only difference is that the original data set has lower precision, or higher residuals/error than the one you post here in the comments. This should be expected and is perfectly normal for empirical data. Something might have influenced the experiment: maybe the external temperature changed abruptly, or charger connection was temporarily lost during charging. Only you can say.

Comment: ... If you don't trust the data, you can discard them and reproduce them. A tip could be to do multiple measurements and average them. Such an approach can greatly reduce noise in empirical data.

Answer (score 2):

After I reviewed the answer of @Magnus, I reduced the limits used for the data in a 3rd order polynomial. As you can see, the points within my crudely drawn red circle cannot both lie on a smooth line with the nearby data. While I could fit smooth lines such as a Hill sigmoidal equation through the data, the data variance (noise) itself appears to be the limiting factor in achieving a peak absolute error of 150 with this data set.

[image: plot]

Comment: Yes, indeed. There is no way you would be able to fit this empirical data to a third degree polynomial, *within the error limit* that OP requests. What @neer really should be doing, is investigating whether or not the error (deviation of each point from the polyfit) follows a trend: if it does, then there's a high probability that a third deg polynomial is **not** the best representation. Else, he should investigate whether (e.g.) [Peirce's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_criterion) is able to remove one or both of these two "trouble points" as outliers.

Comment: I am not able to post the data in tabular form but this is the sequence of difference in values for point: -1119.33945
758.76649
627.20338
461.34722
277.57401
-1683.74025
1681.78044
-245.48792
-361.16933
-424.88779
-420.2673
-334.93186
-152.50547
139.38787
566.12416
374.0794
188.62959
27.15073
-89.98118
-145.39014
-121.70015
So there is no pattern in the difference. Also i don't see if there are only two points with the issue exists.

Comment: After reducing the degree also i see the difference is still not steady: -299.927724
1086.531101
592.701276
179.582801
-150.824324
-2172.520099
1204.495476
-653.777599
-657.339324
-580.189699
-420.328724
-179.756399
143.527276
547.522301
1043.228676
862.646401
616.775476
308.615901
-55.832324
-473.569199
-941.594724

Comment: @neer if you look st the errors at the curve endpoints, far from the two example points I have highlighted, you will see values outside of the "150 limit". Even if you remove the two circled points from the regression, that limit cannot be reached with a smooth curve. This means that the noise in the data set will not allow that limit on this data.

Comment: @neer .. and perhaps more importantly, **why** is it not good enough? Can you shed some light on your error requirements?